# Save string as one of object's property and copy into a list

Tags: c#, list

So I have a class here:

```
public class Product
    {
        public bool Status { get; set; } = false;
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; } = null;
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

After obtaining a `string` result for **SerialNumber**  where I would like to store it as `Product.SerialNumber`. And after that I would like to move it into a list which I declared as `List<Product> = new List<Product>` . How do I exactly do that?

Comment: I'm assuming that by "attribute" you mean "properties", since there is a specific thing called [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/) in .NET and that's not what you're using.

Comment: I recommend reading [this C# fundamentals article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/objects), which covers instantiating objects.

Comment: What does "save" mean? A database? A file on disk? A property assignment? ...

Comment: The `=false` and `=null` are redundant

Comment: @CaiusJard No, I just want the string result to be stored as `Product.SerialNumber` then move it into the `List<Product>`

Comment: You forgot to give your List variable a name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would probably end up looking something like this:

```
var result = somethingThat.GetSerialNumber();

var p = new Product();
p.SerialNumber = result;

var lst = new List<Product>();
lst.Add(p);
```

Or this, if you want to use initializers:

```
var result = somethingThat.GetSerialNumber();

var p = new Product { SerialNumber = result };

var lst = new List<Product> { p };
```

You said in a comment on another answer:

> What if I have 12 different serial numbers to add? Is there any efficient way to do so?

```
var serials = new[]{"1","2","3", ..., "12"}; //note ... is not valid C#, it's a human abbreviation

var lst = new List<Product>(serials.Select(s => new Product { SerialNumber = s}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to do something like this:

```
// Instantiate a list of Products
List<Product> myList = new List<Product>();

// Instantiate an object of class Product
Product myProduct1 = new Product();

// Set the property with the value you want
myProduct1.SerialNumber = "1";

// Add the newly created product to the list
myList.Add(myProduct1);
```

Comment: What if I have 12 different serial numbers to add? Is there any efficient way to do so?

Comment: Instantiate an object, set the serial number and add it to the list in a loop that runs for each serial number you have.

By "efficient way", I guess you mean performance.  For most real-world scenarios, running the above in a loop for 12 times should not be an issue.  Is there a specific constraint/requirement of performance in your application?